# PHP sending variable to other page

Tags: php, mysql, post, get

I have a form, on isset function data is inserted in db also it returns a variable named id from db. i want to post this variable to next page. 
here is code;

```
if (isset($_POST['preview'])){


echo $user = $_SESSION['ue'];
echo $title=$_POST['title'];
echo $dis=$_POST['dis'];
echo $a=$_POST['a'];
echo $b=$_POST['b'];
echo $c=$_POST['c'];
echo $d=$_POST['d'];
echo $timespan=$_POST['timespan'];

$sql="INSERT INTO survey (user, title, description, opta, optb,optc,optd,time) VALUES ('$user','$title', '$dis', '$a' , '$b', '$c', '$d','timespan')";
if (mysqli_query($con,$sql))
 {
  echo "Success";
 }
 else
  {
  echo "Error: " . mysql_error();
  }
  $id = mysqli_insert_id($con); //variable to send to next page


mysqli_close($con); 

}
?>
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It depends: how do you get to the next page? If you are using `header()` then you can append the id as a get-parameter (query-string).

Comment: not using header() just using isset(). actually next page is not and interface it is just a php script.

Comment: Save in session then just clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send it not next page using GET attribute in url as:

```
header("Location: http://mydomain.com/myOtherPage.php?id=".$id);
```

In myOtherPage you can use:

```
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{

$idFromPreviousPage=$_GET['id'];

}
```